# Enable pcre support in clamav yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, pkg-config

How to enable pcre support for clamav in Yocto

This is mentioned in clamav recipe of meta-security

```
PACKAGECONFIG[pcre] = "--with-pcre=${STAGING_LIBDIR},  --without-pcre, libpcre"
```

Adding the below to conf/local.conf is not working

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-clamav_append = 'pcre'
```

Can you please provide a solution on enabling pcre support. I want to avoid PCRE Errors which happens when we do clamscan.

Answer (score 3):

Your Configuration line should be

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-clamav = " pcre"
```

Note the location of 'append' and the extra whitespace in the string

Comment: I am getting the following error now: configure: error: cannot locate libpcre2 or libpcre at /home/panther2/panther2_warrior/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/clamav/0.99.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib64

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in clamav build system (or the recipe depending on how you look at it) that wasn't tested by meta-security recipe writer. The clamav configuration uses "pcre-config", a script provided by pcre. Typically scripts like that do not work for cross-compilation at all so they are not made available during a Yocto/Openembedded build. Typically the best solution to this is to modify the clamav build to use pkg-config to find pcre instead: pcre  supports this and Yoctos pkg-config works correctly in a cross-compile environment.

Comment: Maybe double checking this at whatever mailing list  meta-security uses is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please help me with some links on pkg-config, i am novice here

Comment: For generic docs this may help https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html#using . The current (pcre-config based) implementation is pretty complex (see https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-devel/blob/0.99/m4/reorganization/libs/pcre.m4) but what it actually seems to do should be accomplished with `PCRE_CPPFLAGS="$(pkgconfig --cflags libpcre)"` and `PCRE_LIBS="$(pkg-config --libs libpcre)"`. I'd suggest testing this stuff outside of yocto first, but once you get to testing in yocto remember to add "inherit pkg-config" to clamav recipe if it doesn't have that already.

Comment: Oh it does seem to actually add those flags to CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS respectively too so you'd have to do the same. modifying an unknown build system is often really a trial and error kind of thing, as I said you may want to ping the meta-security devs, maybe they have some clamav specific knowledge (I've never seen the code before)